# Конфликт скрипта с bootstrap.min.js

Tags: javascript

Есть конфликт приведенного внизу кода скрипта с частью кода из bootstrap.min.js

Скрипт копирует value и цену из input в `<p class="item_price"></p>`.
Он не работает если в строке `<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">` присутствует `data-toggle="buttons"`. Если атрибут удалить - начинает работать. Попробуйте.
Но тогда отвалится другая функция - выделения активного label-а класом active. Она работает через bootstrap.min.js.

Как изменить скрипт чтобы они работали без конфликта?

```html
<link href="https://amberroom.rv.ua/wp-content/themes/amberroombs/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://amberroom.rv.ua/wp-content/themes/amberroombs/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row price-and-ctaform">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <p class="item_price" style="color:white;text-align:center">0.00</p><p class="item_Size" style="color:white;text-align:center">?</p>
  <div class="price">
   <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn btn-price">
    20 на 20 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="20×20"> 450 грн.
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-price active">
    30 на 30 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" checked value="30×30"> 910 грн.
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-price">
    40 на 40 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="40×40"> 1335 грн.
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-price">
    50 на 50 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="50×50"> 1800 грн.
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-price">
    60 на 60 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="60×60"> 2250 грн.
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-price">
    80 на 80 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="80×80"> 4000 грн.
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-price">
    100 на 100 см — <input type="radio"name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="100×100"> 6300 грн.
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-price">
    <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="свій розмір"> свій розмір
     </label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script async='async' src="https://amberroom.rv.ua/wp-content/themes/amberroombs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="entry.2145715766"]').forEach(el=>el.onclick=e=>{
   document.querySelector('.item_price').textContent = e.target.nextSibling.textContent;
   document.querySelector('.item_Size').textContent = el.value;
});
</script>
```

Comment: используй addEventListener вместо присваивания  onclick

Comment: не помогло к сожалению

Comment: сделай [mcve] чтобы было ясно что именно не работает

Comment: сделал пример, посмотрите пожалуйста, а то совсем замучился

Comment: добавь еще описание что именно не работает, например что-то должно выводиться или класс меняться

Comment: добавил описание

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74234/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, click на самом деле срабатывает на `label`, а не на `input`. В плагине для bootstrap для него вызывается `.preventDefault()` и до инпута `click` не доходит.

Однако, вызывается событие `change`, если кнопка стала отмечена, именно на него и можно подписаться.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="entry.2145715766"]').forEach(el => el.onchange = e => {
  document.querySelector('.item_price').textContent = e.target.nextSibling.textContent;
  document.querySelector('.item_Size').textContent = el.value;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://amberroom.rv.ua/wp-content/themes/amberroombs/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://amberroom.rv.ua/wp-content/themes/amberroombs/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row price-and-ctaform">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p class="item_price" style="color:white;text-align:center">0.00</p>
    <p class="item_Size" style="color:white;text-align:center">?</p>
    <div class="price">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    20 на 20 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="20×20"> 450 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price active">
    30 на 30 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" checked value="30×30"> 910 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    40 на 40 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="40×40"> 1335 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    50 на 50 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="50×50"> 1800 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    60 на 60 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="60×60"> 2250 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    80 на 80 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="80×80"> 4000 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    100 на 100 см — <input type="radio"name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="100×100"> 6300 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="свій розмір"> свій розмір
     </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script async='async' src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое