# Копирование значения input при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт копирует value и цену из выбранного input в `<p class="item_price"></p>` и в `<p class="item_Size"></p>`.

Как добавить еще скрипт который будет делать тоже самое при загрузке страницы для выбранного по умолчанию `<input checked>`?

Разбор багов скрипта здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795901/191574

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="entry.2145715766"]').forEach(el => el.onchange = e => {
  document.querySelector('.item_price').textContent = e.target.nextSibling.textContent;
  document.querySelector('.item_Size').textContent = el.value;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://amberroom.rv.ua/wp-content/themes/amberroombs/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://amberroom.rv.ua/wp-content/themes/amberroombs/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row price-and-ctaform">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p class="item_price" style="color:white;text-align:center">0.00</p>
    <p class="item_Size" style="color:white;text-align:center">?</p>
    <div class="price">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    20 на 20 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="20×20"> 450 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price active">
    30 на 30 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" checked value="30×30"> 910 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    40 на 40 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="40×40"> 1335 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    50 на 50 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="50×50"> 1800 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    60 на 60 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="60×60"> 2250 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    80 на 80 см — <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="80×80"> 4000 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    100 на 100 см — <input type="radio"name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="100×100"> 6300 грн.
     </label>
        <label class="btn btn-price">
    <input type="radio" name="entry.2145715766" id="entry_2145715766" value="свій розмір"> свій розмір
     </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял цель, то тебе нужно что бы при загрузке в нужном месте прописывалось то, что выбрано по умолчанию. Такое может сделать, например, такой код

```
let checkedInput = document.querySelector('input:checked');
document.querySelector('.item_price').textContent = checkedInput.nextSibling.textContent;
document.querySelector('.item_Size').textContent = checkedInput.value;
```